# ListView NotifyDataSetChanged Problem() on Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am currently developing a android app which has a list view which is populated with data from the android SQLite Database.

I am calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but for some reason it is not showing the new information populated from the database. Below is some of the code that I am using.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.show_login_box, LOGINS);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myDB.close();
            c.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

try `adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Instead, use the `listView1.setAdapter(adapter)` function to refresh the listview.